# Rails SQL - create buckets, and get counts of records in each bucket

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a **Jobs** table with a column for **salary**.

How can I bucket the salaries into groups of $10,000, and then get a count of how many jobs are in each bucket?

An answer that uses Rails active record is preferable, but given the difficulty I'll accept raw SQL answers as well.

**Starting Data**

```
Jobs

id      salary (integer)
-----------------
1       93,530
2       72,400
3       120,403
4       193,001
...
```

**Result Data**

```
bucket               job_count
----------------------------
$0 - $9,999          0
$10,000 - $19,999    0
$20,000 - $29,999    3
$30,000 - $39,999    5
$40,000 - $49,999    12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another SQL-based solution.

Obtain bucket for each salary like this:

```
select 
  FLOOR(salary/10000) as bucket
from jobs
```

Use `GROUP BY` to do the counting:

```
select 
  bucket, 
  count(*)
from (
    select FLOOR(salary/10000) as bucket
    from jobs
) as t1
GROUP BY bucket
```

Finally, add the ranges instead of bucket number:

```
select 
  CONCAT('$', FORMAT(bucket*10000,0), ' - $', FORMAT((bucket+1)*10000-1,0)) as range, 
  job_count
from ( 
    select bucket, count(*) as job_count
    from (
        select FLOOR(salary/10000) as bucket
        from jobs
    ) as t1
    GROUP BY bucket
) as t2
```

Note that the functions used are for MySQL. YMMV.

Comment: Note that this one may leave out empty ranges.

Answer (score 0):

From an SQL perspective there are several approaches. Here is one.

```
-- First, create a report table (temporarily here, but could be permanent):

create table salary_report (
  bucket      integer,
  lower_limit integer,
  upper_limit integer,
  job_count   integer
);

-- populate the table
-- note this could (and probably should) be automated, not hardcoded
insert into salary_report values (1,00000,09999,0);
insert into salary_report values (2,10000,19999,0);
insert into salary_report values (3,20000,29999,0);
insert into salary_report values (4,30000,39999,0);
insert into salary_report values (5,40000,49999,0);

-- set correct counts
update salary_report as sr
  set job_count = (
    select count(*)
    from jobs as j
    where j.salary between sr.lower_limit and sr.upper_limit
    );

-- finally, access the data (through activerecord?)
-- note: not formatted as dollar amounts
select concat( sr.lower_limit,' - ',sr.upper_limit) as range, job_count, bucket
from salary_report
order by bucket;

-- drop table if required
drop table salary_report;
```

I have tried to keep the SQL generic, but *exact syntax may vary depending upon your RDBMS.*
No SQL Fiddle provided because it seems to be broken today.